How do I marshal to JSON a struct with terraform tfsdk annotations and with types.X types?
I have structs that I am populating with data from TF state. Those structs use types.X types and have tfsdk annotations. When I try to marshal those structs to JSON, all the fields are unpopulated.
type MyStruct struct {
  Foo types.String `tfsdk:"foo"`
}

Within a Create function:
var state MyStruct
req.Plan.Get(&state)

// I want a JSON representation of state
enc, _ := json.Marshal(state)
// fields of enc are empty

How do I marshal MyStruct to JSON?

You need a corresponding struct with types that can be serialized/deserialized and marshalled/unmarshalled (tag below is actually optional since the member is named the same as the key):
type MyGoStruct struct {
  Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

then you need some kind of converter between the two structs. I believe in Go you could define this for the interface (similar to std::convert::Into traits in Rust), but that would probably be overkill:
func myStructToMyGoStruct(myStruct MyStruct) MyGoStruct {
  return MyGoStruct{Foo: myStruct.Foo.ValueString()}
}

Note that if you were converting to a TF type then you also normally need to input context.Context and return diag.Diagnostics, but this is converting from a TF type.
Now you can serialize and marshal as expected:
goState := myStructToMyGoStruct(state)
enc, _ := json.Marshal(goState)

Note that there is probably a package in or utilized by the Hashicorp Packer and/or Terraform ecosystem somewhere that serializes to HCL and JSON simultaneously, but I am unsure what that may be. If I had to speculate it would probably be related to go-cty which would mean Mart would know and he can update on that.
